# Large Primary key affecting performance?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site, and as a result of a plugin, my posts and postmeta table IDs got set to autoincrement at 9004111220000000 and up. I didn't notice until I had 10s of thousands of IDs like that.

My question is, is this a significant enough hit to performance that I should do something about it?

Comment: BIGINT size does not depend on the value.

Comment: It would sure be nice to know which plugin did this...

Answer (score 0):

Given its still a 64bit number << 2^64-1 (the `BIGINT UNSIGNED` maximum, that I assume posts and postmeta uses) its ok. It uses more bits of a bigint than usual, but its ok.

I wouldn't expect a degradation because of this.

If you still use the plugin, I hope you see what it is doing.